# What are divine tears/anagogic orts and why am I obtaining them?

Tags: runescape

While skilling and killing monsters, some mysterious divine tears/anagogic orts appear in my currency pouch or as part of the monster loot. What are they? And what do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are part of a clan with an Clan Avatar, you will have a chance of obtaining [anagogic orts](https://runescape.wiki/w/Anagogic_ort) from skilling or from monsters. With 300 orts, you can interact with your Clan Avatar to receive [one of seven special buffs](https://runescape.wiki/w/Clan_avatar#Buffs) for a week (Credit to the (unofficial) *RuneScape Wiki* for the following info):

- Heal Over Time  ---  Heals clan members in range of the avatar for ~0.2% of their maximum lifepoints every five seconds.
- Familiar Faces  ---  Doubles the familiar's timer when summoning one in range of the avatar. Entering the area of effect with a summoned familiar, or summoning a creature within the area of effect, will double the time for which they can be active. The effect is lost if you leave the area of effect.
- Auto Ort  ---  The avatar adds dropped/skilled Anagogic orts straight into your inventory when collected in range of the avatar.
- Skill Plot Bonus  ---  10% more resources per minute from skilling in the citadel; this does not increase the cap for the individual, but instead increases the rate of resources produced. Note that XP gained per minute does not change, so after reaching your cap you will have received ~9.1% less XP!
- Skilling Bonus  ---  3% more xp for skilling on the same world as the avatar and 6% more xp for skilling in range of the avatar.
- Random Resurrection  --- Resurrects a player. This can only be done to each player once a day and for a limited amount of total times per clan per day depending on the citadel tier.
- Protector ---- The avatar takes some of the damage dealt to a clan member in range of the avatar.

Note that you can only receive 200 orts a day.

Also, many players consider getting the ort drop as annoying. There **is** a way to disable getting the orts as a drop. Talk to the Captain of the Guard at the Clan Camp (Easily reachable with a Clan Vexillum).

---

[**Divine tears**](https://runescape.wiki/w/Divine_tears) act as the same way as orts (except they appear in your inventory instead of on the ground, unless they are found from combat). However, their use is completely different.

With *RuneScape 3*, the Battle of Lumbridge now occurs. If you follow either Saradomin or Zamorak, you can collect divine tears from the battleground (and also from skilling/monster drops). You can deposit these at collection points beside either God. You deposit these to help your God defeat the other God, obtaining the energy underneath them.

As a reward for depositing the tears, you get to vote on a buff which will be activated in approximately 2 days on 17 hours since posting this answer (the amount of votes you get is 1/10th of the amount of tears you deposit). Also, you will obtain renown (the amount is the same as the amount of tears deposited), which can be used to purchase level 75 hybrid armour, experience lamps, or even emotes and titles.

You can only obtain 3,000 tears a day, or 1,320 tears if you are free-to-play.

---

Source:

- The Clan Avatar list of boosts is from [here](https://runescape.wiki/w/Clan_avatar#Buffs). Other pages I have linked can be used for future reading.

Comment: Copying straight from the wiki is plagiarism and is illegal. Give credit to your sources.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I linked the wiki, is that not allowed?

Comment: It's illegal you must put at the bottom of the page where you got your sources.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I made it a bit more obvious that it's fmor the wiki. Sorry

Comment: @YoungGuilo How is it now?